# Bronze tier does not restrict to one request per minute in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have published an API with tier availability as bronze.

When I subscribe to that API as a different user in the store, bronze will be the only available tier to subscribe.After subscription, when I try accessing the API, I am able to hit it many times in a minute without any restriction. Why does it not restrict me for 1 request per minute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your local install of WSO2 API Manager or [API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud/) service? In [API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud/), the tiers are all presetup and work flawlessly as far as I can tell.

For your local API Manager set up the couple things I would look at are:

1. Check whether the APIs that you set up require authorization - if you set them up as public without authorization key requirement - then I think there is no tier enforcement either because your tier cannot be verified without authorization.
2. Check your ties.xml to ensure that the throttling level for the tier is properly set up: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Managing+Throttling+Tiers

Comment: I am using local install of WSO2 API manager.The tiers.xml looks fine. Can you please let me know how to set up authorization for my APIs?  What is the relation between tier enforcement and authorization?

Comment: When invoking the API are you using authorization header? E.g. curl -H "Authorization:Bearer Ob0yTHSYOvtbfy9_mQqmQrBBVYUa" -v 'http://gateway.api.cloud.wso2.com:8280/t/yashiracom/phoneverify/1.0.0/CheckPhoneNumber?PhoneNumber=123456&LicenseKey=0'

This authorization header provides information on who the subscriber is, and thus you can enforce throttling.

You can make this a required header for a resource on the last step of API configuration (Manage). I think default is "Application & Application User" which makes it indeed mandatory, but if you set to None - it will mean anonymous access.

Comment: Yes. I am using authorization:bearer while invoking.And I am not changing the default value.